# Regex behaviour with angle brackets

Tags: regex, grep

Please explain to me why the following expression doesn't output anything:

```
echo "<firstname.lastname@domain.com>" | egrep "<lastname@domain.com>"
```

but the following does:

```
echo "<firstname.lastname@domain.com>" | egrep "\<lastname@domain.com>"
```

The behaviour of the first is as expected but the second should not output.  Is the "\<" being ignored within the regex or causing some other special behaviour?

Comment: `\<` matches the beginning of a word.

Comment: @hwnd no, it won't work with this `echo "name.lastname@domain.com" | egrep "\<.lastname@domain.com"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AS @hwnd said `\<` matches the begining of the word. `ie` a word boundary `\b` must exists before the starting  word character(*character after `\<` in the input must be a word character*),

In your example,

```
echo "<firstname.lastname@domain.com>" | egrep "<lastname@domain.com>"
```

In the above example, egrep checks for a literal `<` character present before the lastname string. But there isn't, so it prints nothing.

```
$ echo "<firstname.lastname@domain.com>" | egrep "\<lastname@domain.com>"
<firstname.**lastname@domain.com>**
```

But in this example,  a word boundary `\b` exists before `lastname` string so it  prints the matched characters.

**Some more examples:**

```
$ echo "namelastname@domain.com" | egrep "\<e@domain.com"
$ echo "namelastname@domain.com" | egrep "\<lastname@domain.com"
$ echo "namelastname@domain.com" | egrep "\<com"
namelastname@domain.**com**
$ echo "<firstname.lastname@domain.com>" | egrep "\<@domain.com>"
$ echo "n-ame-lastname@domain.com" | egrep "\<ame-lastname@domain.com"
n-**ame-lastname@domain.com**
```